# Не устанавливается xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

Поставил на виртуальную машину osx mountain lion обновил до el capitan
хотел устнановить себе xcode  и сразу вылазит окно  - "xcode cannot be installed on macintosh because osx version 10.11 or later is required"
помогите решить если кто знает.

Comment: 10.11 это и есть el capitan. точно она установилась у вас?

Comment: Да установилось. но в версии почему то пишет 10.8.5 и обновлений на более высокую версию нет

Comment: @Anton а как вы поняли, что установилось, если сама система думает, что нет?

Comment: Сколько не имел дела с виртуалками (через VMware - самое простое) или хикнтошами - не стоит это того (особенно, если это для разработки). Лучше не тратить время впустую и сразу купить мак (начать копить, потом купить). Только не старше 2 лет!

Answer (score 0):

ну тут <strike>три</strike> два варианта:

1. Искать версию xcode младше чем в сторе (на торрентах есть сам на старый хакинтош ставил), но не будет последних версий систем для симулятора(и девайсов скорее всего), последней версии swift, и стор может не пустить вашу апу
2. Искать на хакинтош osx version 10.11 и выше
3. Купить мак